# Sort by Year, Month, Date in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have done some searching around and haven't yet found an answer for this one.

I have an object `Task` that stores a date in a`StringBuilder` in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`. It comes from a `DateSpinner`. I chose to store it as `StringBuilder` because I completely forgot I was going to sort my list of `Task(s)` later on.

What I'm asking is effectively if it's better to rewrite the class and Activity code and store as a Date, then use a `Comparator`, or whether I should (as I'm currently attempting to do) create a temporary date for each object and then use this to sort the list

Google has shown me the radix sort, but I've not seen a way to do it to sort by three ways.

Task Class

```
public Task(String identifier, String name, String description, ArrayList<TeamMember> members, int hours, StringBuilder date) {
    this.id = identifier;
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = description;
    this.members = new ArrayList<>();
    this.hours = hours;
    this.date = date;

}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public ArrayList<TeamMember> getMembers() {
    return members;
}

public int getHours() {
    return hours;
}

public StringBuilder getDate() {
    return date;
}
}
```

And my initial (WIP) attempt at sorting by date

```
    for(Task t : tasks){
        String dateString = t.getDate().toString();
        List<String> date = Arrays.asList(dateString.split("/"));
        Calendar c =  Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Integer.parseInt(date.get(0)),Integer.parseInt(date.get(1))-1,Integer.parseInt(date.get(2)));
        Task temp = t;

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: *"If it's better to rewrite the class and Activity code and store as a Date, then use a Comparator"* Although this question can attract opinionated answers, I guess you should do it if it's not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your data model as it is if you want to save some time, what you can do is :

sort the `list` with the `Tasks`, but use the `collection` and pass an annonymous `comparator`, in there parse the string date to a Date Object and compare the list elements with that date as criteria.

at the end all the `Tasks` in the list will be correctly sorted by the date.

## An example:

```
Collections.sort(yourTasksList, new Comparator<Task>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Task o1, Task o2) {
        try {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/yyyy").parse(o1.getDate().toString()).compareTo(new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/yyyy").parse(o2.getDate().toString()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return 0;
        }
        }
    });
```

and add a `System.out.println(yourTasksList);`

Comment: This gives me an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'Y'` - I'm assuming that's a fault with the way my Date is stored?

Comment: you are right in android you have to use yyyy (lowercase only)...
i will update my answer

Comment: `DD` should be lowercase, `dd`.

Answer (score 0):

The [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35828370/642706) by Xoce is correct.

## Avoid old date-time classes

In addition, I would advise ditching the use of the troublesome old date-time classes, java.text.SimpleDateFormat and java.util.Date/Calendar. Those classes have proven to be confusing and flawed. And they lack a true date-only class without time-of-day nor time zone.

## java.time

I certainly would store the date-only value in your class as a date-only object, specifically the [`LocalDate`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/LocalDate.html) class found in the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

JSR 310 defines the spec for java.time. Inspired by the highly successful Joda-Time project.

## ThreeTen-Backport

Android does not yet have Java 8 technology, so I suggest using the [Android-specific wrapped version](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) of the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project which implements java.time-style classes for older Java implementations.

Parse that input string.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "23/01/2016" , formatter );
```

If you need ”today“ be sure to specify the time zone as the date varies around the globe for any particular moment.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

In that code seen in Xoce’s Answer, replace that `return` line with:

```
return o1.localDate.compareTo( o2.localDate );
```